# Make a floating div have a dynamic 100% height

Tags: html, css

I am using php to dynamically create webpages. As such I have things more objectified. My generic page creates a header, a mainbody and a footer. The content is the placed inside of my mainbody.

- Mainbody has a min-height of 600px.
- A div inside of mainbody for one page acts as a menu on the left side of mainbody. I want this div to be 100% of the height of the mainbody.
- The div (menu) is floating left, and the rest of the mainbody content is generated dynamically by the php.

What doesn't Work:

- height:100%; (It just ends up being the height of the content I have inside the menu, not the height of the mainbody)
- min-height:600px; (It just stays 600px, even when mainbody gets larger)
- Haven't played with it enough, but position absolute, absurdly large height, and a negative z index, and mainbody overflow...not successful with the little bit I tried.

Any ideas? I'm totally open to doing any kind of weird manipulation, so long as it looks natural.

Here's example code: [jsfiddle.net/TButx](http://jsfiddle.net/TButx)

Comment: loo into using javascript to get the height of your current screen and set the height of the current element to the desired 100%

Comment: do you have to code we can see somewhere?  This ki'tnd of problem is much easier to solve if we can see it.  If you can put the file online can you try replicate it with a JSFIddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TButx/ There ya go! I want the menu to always be the full height of the mainbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TButx/56/

The solution is to pad the bottom of the column and hide overflow.

```
#html{width:400px; height:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:yellow;}
#mainbody {min-height:300px; height:100%; overflow: hidden;}
#menu {width:100px; height:inherit; background-color:blue; float:left; padding-bottom: 700px;margin-bottom: -700px;}
#content {height:100%; width:300px; background-color:red; float:right; padding-bottom: 500px;margin-bottom: -500px;}
#clear {clear: both;}​

<div id="html">
<div id="mainbody">
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be an error in your code. As you describe it, everything should  work.
Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/VxSA3/

HTML:

```
<div id="Mainbody">
    <div id="menu">menu content</div>
    <p>some text in the main-body</p>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Mainbody{height:600px;outline:1px solid green;}
#menu{height:100%;outline:2px solid red;float:left;width:100px;}​
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/HpSbT This image shows the one that looks correct (using #mainbody min-height: 600px; and the content does not make it any larger. #menu height: 600px;) http://imgur.com/ZYR0h On this one you can see that the height does not extend to the bottom of the body that was extended by the size of the text.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with this is that your main body div isn't wrapping around your floating elements. You have to have a div in it with `clear:both` and the body div will stretch.

As an alternative method, you can use absolute position to control the stretch of the menu div.

For the main body div:

```
position:relative;
```

For the left floated div (no longer left floated in this case):

```
position:absolute;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
top:0px;
width:...
```